# What is the correct REST Endpoint to retrieve user (profile) information from a connections installation

Tags: oauth, opensocial, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Based on this information: 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=OpenSocial_Profiles_API_sbar&content=pdcontent

And a working url for posting updates:

I created this one to try and find out to whom this access token belongs:

https://connections4.e-office.com/connections/opensocial/oauth/rest/people/@me/@self

But than I get Error 501: No service defined for path people/@me/@self

what should the url be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently you don't need to include: @Self

This is it:

connections/opensocial/oauth/rest/people/@me/

See also : http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/B49DB47061DA9DEB85257AC9006D5256/attach/AppDev_OpenSocial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Profiles REST API URLs:

```
http(s)://yourserver/profiles/admin/atom/profileEntry.do?email=mailaddress
```

or

```
http(s)://yourserver/profiles/admin/atom/profileEntry.do?uid=uid
```